# Rails - How to make a form submit to a specific controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I'm doing some learning and want to create a blog where I have a controller that provides views to the public viewing my blog in a standard blog layout while I want to have a separate controller 'admin/posts' that allows me to view the posts in a separate layout.

I've created the two controllers and used namespace in routes for the 'admin/posts' controller. I've also made a form to submit a new post in the 'admin/posts' views but when the form submits it goes to the create action on the posts folder.. is there a way to tell a form you want it to submit to the 'admin/posts/create' action?

I'm using the 'simple_form' gem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick.

```
<%= simple_form_for([@admin, @post]) do |f| %>
```

Comment: Thanks you put me in the right direction.

I did what you said and it still redirected me to the 'posts' controller to try and create the post which I dont want to happen..

So I realised that @admin doesn't exist but tried ['admin', @post] and that did the trick!